# Obtener datos de un Fragment dentro de un Activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Tengo un Activity en el cuál registro a los usuarios y en esta misma Activity tengo incorporado un Fragment que me muestra el mapa de Google Maps, lo que quiero es poder pasar los datos que recojo del Fragment de Google Maps hacia la Activity para poder guardar los datos posteriormente en la base de datos.

Los datos que recojo del Fragment de Google Maps son la dirección, latitud y longitud. Estos tres datos los quiero pasar desde el Fragment que se encuentra dentro de la Activity, hacia la Activity que contiene el Fragment.

Este es el código donde tengo los datos que quiero pasar, los cuales son: fulladdress, position.latitude y position.longitude.

La idea es que al marcar un punto (markerOptions) en el Fragment de Google Maps, se transfieran los datos automaticamente y se autorellene el cuadro de EditText que dice "Dirección de la empresa" con el dato obtenido "fulladdress".

```
markerOptions
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
                            .title(fulladdress);
                    LatLng position = markerOptions.getPosition();
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            "Lat " + position.latitude + " "
                                    + "Long " + position.longitude,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con una interfaz que sirvira de comunicador entre el fragment y la actividad.

Crea una interfaz llamada `DataShare.java` con un método llamado `setData(objet data)`:

```
public interface DataShare
{
  void setData(object data);
}
```

Ahora define un metodo en tu fragment que acepte una instancia de la interfaz:

```
public class TuFragmento extends Fragment
{
   //... 


   private DataShare shareableInstance;
   public void setSharableInstance(DataShare share) {
      this.shareableInstance = share;
   }

}
```

Ahora has que tu actividad implemente la interfaz y define que quiere que haga cuando se ejecute el metodo `setData`:

```
public class MainActivity implements DataShare
{
  void onCreate(...) {
    //...
  }

  @Override
  public void setData(object data)
  {
     if(data instanceof Integer)
     {
        Integer numero = (Integer)data;
        // hacer lo que desees con la data
     }
  }
}
```

Entonces cuando obtengas la referencia del fragment en el activity, le envías la referencia de la implementacion del Activity:

```
public class MainActivity implements DataShare
{
  void onCreate(...) {
    //...
    fragment.setData(this)
  }
//...
```

Entonces desde tu fragmento ahora solo tendrás que ejecutar el método `shareableInstance.setData()` para compartir la data desde el fragment hasta el activity. Esto hara que se ejecute el metodo `setData()` de la instancia de la actividad:

```
public void Metodo()
{
   // en algun lugar de tu fragment
   this.shareableData.setData(333); // <-- esto ejecutara el metodo setData del activity ya que pertenece a su instancia
}
```

Comment: No logro implementarlo, no me funciona :/